# Make every function in a PHP class refer to the same database row

Tags: php, class, oop

Looking to make a class that will be for 'customers'. The purpose of this class is to pass in some details, and then either add a user or update an existing one.

After this, I might also want to do to more things with this 'customer'.

Im new to classes so need to know how to always refer to the same row no matter what i'm doing with the current initiated class.

Basic use:

```
$customer = new Customer($customer_details);
```

When creating a new instance of this class, I want it to straight away add / update a row.

However, as well as this later on I might want to update a specific field:

```
$customer->setValue('firstname','Craig');
```

But I dont want to have to do another lookup to get the row ID etc in this fucntion. I want `$customer` to always reference the user given the `$customer_info`.

Comment: `$customer->info = $customer_info`? It's an instance of an object - you can store stuff in it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, when you create a new Customer, you're inserting into the db right away? If that's the case you can get the ID back from the database and have it stored in the object at $this->id in the constructor. And later you can make your setValues update that ID in the database. But, I think it would be generally better to store all the customer data in the object itself, and then when you've got it to where you want it to be, save it to the database and do one insert with all your data at once.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want `setValue()` to update the database, I would advise creating a field in your `Customer` class that contains the identifier for the row in the database.

```
/**
 * Database identifier.
 *
 * @var string/int
 */
 private $id;
```

Have your constructor set the value of the identifier on object creation using `$this->id = $id`.  Then your `setValue()` call can use that identifier to update the information in the database.

EDIT

If you are creating a new `Customer` instead of updating an existing one (passing new data to the constructor) the database controller that you are using should have a means to get the ID of the new row (given it is an auto-incremented value).  Otherwise the ID is something that you are generating, in which case you could just set the field value in the class.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're referring to the [Active Record Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern#Implementations). You can find many implementations in PHP, such as [Propel](http://propelorm.org/documentation/03-basic-crud.html).